# How do I run some VBA code when a cell is changed?

Tags: excel, vba, eventtrigger

I want to add some VBA code when the value in a cell changes.

I've already tried `Worksheet_Change()` as described at [Contextures](http://www.contextures.com/xlfaqmac.html#WSChange) however, this won't work: it only fires when the user changes the value. I want to fire it whenever the value changes, i.e. whenever the spreadsheet recalculates.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
   MsgBox "Something recalculated", vbOKOnly, "Testing Actions"

End Sub
```